# How to filter menu context based on file suffix condition

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Trying to author a vscode extension to resize an image file. I want to right click an image file type in the explorer to trigger the extension.

I've got the selected item file path from explorer view by passing a `vscode.URI` parameter to the command from the initial context. But I have a question regarding how to filter the menu to only appear on images:

How can I only show the menu context item when the file is an image type? Is there way to specify something like this in the extension context?

```json
{
   "when": "resourceFilename == CA375AS062_princeton_3750_angle_shader_paint_brush_size_5_8__1000.jpg",
   "title": "Resize Image",
   "command": "fireshop.resizeImage",
   "group": "fireshop-nav"
}
```

This condition works so left side is right, but I want to detect just the file suffix as `.jpg, .jpeg, .png` etc. Is it possible? (the docs on the when conditions needs some improvement!)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use `resourceExtname` to "filter" on extension name.

```json
{
    "command": "fireshop.resizeImage",
    "group": "navigation",
    "when": "resourceExtname == .jpg"
}
```

It was implemented in [Oct, 10th with PR 34889](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/34889/files)